# How to upload a table to Shiny app to then sort it into multiple mini tables for downloading

Tags: r, loops, shiny, download

I am creating a Shiny application to sort out a table into multiple little tables. My code works as an R script, only now I am trying to convert it into a Shiny app.
Inputs work well (file upload, text input etc.).
However there are two problems with the output:

1. I can not work out how to download the multiple tables - would a for loop work? Also, in which section should the data be separated into multiple tables.
2. 'output' is not recognised. Many thanks for any help.

This is my draft code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput("upload", NULL, accept = c(".txt")),
    textInput('modification', 'Modification'),
    textInput('date', 'Date as specified in filenames', '20230502'),
    textInput('file_numbers', 'Enter a vector (comma delimited)', "0,1,2"),
    tableOutput("table"),
    textOutput('heading2'),
    downloadButton('download', 'Download.xlsx')
    )


    server <- function(input, output, session) {
    options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)
    data <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)
    table <- read_delim(input$upload$datapath, delim = "\t", escape_double = FALSE, 
                        col_names = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
    })
  
    ## ------------- Create the modified table
    heights_table2 <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)
    MS_data <- read_delim(input$upload$datapath, delim = "\t", escape_double = FALSE, 
                          col_names = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
    # --------------------------------------------------------
    ## Modify the table (shortened version)
    # --------------------------------------------------------
    MS_data$count <- sapply(MS_data$count, sub_comma)
    MS_data <- MS_data
    })
  
    # add heading to tbl displayed on Shiny, to see what we get before actually downloading
    output$heading2 <- reactive({
    paste('Top rows of the modified table')
    })
  
    output$table <- renderTable({
    # paste0('Top of processed results to download'),
    head(heights_table2())
    })
  
    ## ------------- Download only the tables I need
    b <- input$date # file name before extension
    lijst <- c()
    l <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(input$file_numbers,","))) # vector, input$file_numbers, entered as   vector
  
    for(a in lijst){
    # d <-  modification # specify which modification we are looking for
    # print(a)
    # print(d)
      filename <- paste0(input$upload$datapath,'MS_', a, '_', modification, '.xlsx')
    # print(filename)
    modification01 <- paste0(modification, ':')
    # print(modification)
    # print(modification01)
    data <- MS_data[grepl(a, MS_data$name) & grepl(modification01, MS_data$name),] 
    write.xlsx(data, filename)
    
    output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      filename <- paste0(input$upload$datapath,'MS_', a, '_', modification, '.xlsx')
      modification01 <- paste0(modification, ':')
      data <- heights_table2(MS_data[grepl(a, MS_data$name) & grepl(modification01, MS_data$name),] 
    }
    content = function(filename) {
      write.xlsx(data, filename)
    }
     )
      } ### 
    ### 
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```